# Adjective ed ending

Tags: american-english, british-english

"She was feeling bored yesterday"

Is that sentence correct?
What her boredom was in progress at that time?

Comment: The sentence is grammatically acceptable.  The final sentence of your question is wonky, do you mean *Was her boredom in progress at that time ?* ?

Answer (score -1):

In the sentence "She was feeling bored yesterday", replace the word 'bored' with 'happy' and see how the word functions? Thus, the word bored is an adjective.

Yesterday being a definitive past, the use of past continuous tense should also be reviewed.  It should ideally be like,  "When I met her yday, she was feeling bored."

Comment: We can use "comments" to post our remarks and opinions.

Comment: Ram, there's nothing wrong with using the continuous tense in this context. Presumably the boredom lasted for some time.

Comment: I second Kate, there is nothing wrong with the Continuous there.